# Kentico IEnumerable<DocumentAttachment> is empty in my controller

Tags: kentico, kentico-12, kentico-mvc, kentico-api

I am using the standard method to get the properties of my page:

```
ClientLogosDatasource datasourceItem = ClientLogosDatasourceProvider.GetClientLogosDatasource(datasourceNodeGuid, "en-us", SiteContext.CurrentSiteName)
.Columns("ClientLogosDatasourceHeadingText", "ClientLogosDatasourceImages");
```

Which has an 'Attachments' form component

[image: 1]

But when I attempt to enumerate over the property in my MVC application, the enumeration is empty.

[image: 1]

Stepping through the code, it basically skips the foreach completely. I'm not sure why the Images property is null/empty.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the basic [API example](https://docs.kentico.com/api12sp/content-management/attachments#Attachments-Gettingtheattachmentsofapage) (not MVC specific) but should get you in the right direction.

```
// Creates a new instance of the Tree provider
TreeProvider tree = new TreeProvider(MembershipContext.AuthenticatedUser);

// Gets a page
TreeNode page = tree.SelectNodes()
    .Path("/Articles")
    .OnCurrentSite()
    .Culture("en-us")
    .TopN(1)
    .FirstOrDefault();

if (page != null)
{
    // Iterates over all attachments of the page
    foreach (DocumentAttachment attachment in page.AllAttachments)
    {
        // Perform any action with the attachment object (DocumentAttachment)
    }
}

// To get only unsorted attachments, use the TreeNode.Attachments collection
// To get only page field attachments, use the TreeNode.GroupedAttachments collection
```